# Cannot compile spring app with graalVM when adding -agentlib options

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, spring-native, paketo

I am currently stuck on a weird issue. I am doing the migration from a SpringBoot JVM app to a GraalVM native one.

To acheive this, I need to override manually the reflectioc-config.json made by GraalVM. To do this, i want to get the autogenerate one by graal, to avoid rewrite everything (And also to know everything he did). But, when I add the `-agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=src/graal` argument, everything goes wrong.

I mean, without this, the native image compile, and run (And later, crash because it miss some initialization), but with this line, it completly crash at the compilation time due to

```
[INFO]     [creator]     Fatal error: JVMTI call failed with JVMTI_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE
[INFO]     [creator]     Error: Image build request failed with exit status 99
```

I basically don't even know what is JVMTI, why it's needed, and why it's a issue now (And so, how to fix it ^^') I googled it, but I didn't found something related with my specific case
Did someone already had this issue with spring-native?

I case you might need it, the full error message:

```
[INFO]     [creator]     Fatal error: JVMTI call failed with JVMTI_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     JavaFrameAnchor dump:
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]       No anchors
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     TopFrame info:
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]       TotalFrameSize in CodeInfoTable 48
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     VMThreads info:
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]       VMThread 00007f264c0249c0  STATUS_IN_JAVA (safepoints disabled)  java.lang.Thread@0x7f264a771850
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     VM Thread State for current thread 00007f264c0249c0:
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]       0 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIThreadLocalEnvironment.jniFunctions = (bytes)
[INFO]     [creator]         00007f264c0249c0: 00007f264a699010
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]       8 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.graal.snippets.StackOverflowCheckImpl.stackBoundaryTL = (Word) 1  0000000000000001
[INFO]     [creator]       16 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.Safepoint.safepointRequested = (int) 2147480300  7ffff2ec
[INFO]     [creator]       20 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.VMThreads$StatusSupport.statusTL = (int) 1  00000001
[INFO]     [creator]       24 (32 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.ThreadLocalAllocation.regularTLAB = (bytes)
[INFO]     [creator]         00007f264c0249d8: 00007f2650100000 00007f2650200000
[INFO]     [creator]         00007f264c0249e8: 00007f2650103688 0000000000000000
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]       56 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.currentThread = (Object) java.lang.Thread  00007f264a771850
[INFO]     [creator]       64 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.stack.JavaFrameAnchors.lastAnchor = (Word) 0  0000000000000000
[INFO]     [creator]       72 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.heap.NoAllocationVerifier.openVerifiers = (Object) null
[INFO]     [creator]       80 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.identityhashcode.IdentityHashCodeSupport.hashCodeGeneratorTL = (Object) null
[INFO]     [creator]       88 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.snippets.ExceptionUnwind.currentException = (Object) null
[INFO]     [creator]       96 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.ThreadingSupportImpl.activeTimer = (Object) null
[INFO]     [creator]       104 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.graal.isolated.IsolatedCompileClient.currentClient = (Object) null
[INFO]     [creator]       112 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.graal.isolated.IsolatedCompileContext.currentContext = (Object) null
[INFO]     [creator]       120 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIObjectHandles.handles = (Object) com.oracle.svm.core.handles.ThreadLocalHandles  00007f26501010a0
[INFO]     [creator]       128 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIThreadLocalPendingException.pendingException = (Object) null
[INFO]     [creator]       136 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIThreadLocalPinnedObjects.pinnedObjectsListHead = (Object) null
[INFO]     [creator]       144 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIThreadOwnedMonitors.ownedMonitors = (Object) null
[INFO]     [creator]       152 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.VMThreads.IsolateTL = (Word) 139802432241664  00007f264a500000
[INFO]     [creator]       160 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.VMThreads.OSThreadHandleTL = (Word) 139802571708160  00007f2652a01700
[INFO]     [creator]       168 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.VMThreads.OSThreadIdTL = (Word) 139802571708160  00007f2652a01700
[INFO]     [creator]       176 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.VMThreads.nextTL = (Word) 0  0000000000000000
[INFO]     [creator]       184 (8 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.VMThreads.unalignedIsolateThreadMemoryTL = (Word) 139802460703120  00007f264c024990
[INFO]     [creator]       192 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.graal.snippets.StackOverflowCheckImpl.yellowZoneStateTL = (int) -16843010  fefefefe
[INFO]     [creator]       196 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.snippets.ImplicitExceptions.implicitExceptionsAreFatal = (int) 0  00000000
[INFO]     [creator]       200 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.ThreadingSupportImpl.currentPauseDepth = (int) 0  00000000
[INFO]     [creator]       204 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.VMThreads$ActionOnExitSafepointSupport.actionTL = (int) 0  00000000
[INFO]     [creator]       208 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.VMThreads$ActionOnTransitionToJavaSupport.actionTL = (int) 0  00000000
[INFO]     [creator]       212 (4 bytes): com.oracle.svm.core.thread.VMThreads$StatusSupport.safepointsDisabledTL = (int) 1  00000001
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     VMOperation dump:
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]       No VMOperation in progress
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]       The 10 most recent VM operation status changes (oldest first):
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Dump Counters:
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Raw Stacktrace:
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]       00007f2652a00a30: 00007f2650103550 00007f2650103628
[INFO]     [creator]       00007f2652a00a40: 00007f2650103668 00007f264a500000
[INFO]     [creator]       00007f2652a00a50: 00007f264ab7a8f9 00007f264ab7a974
[INFO]     [creator]       00007f2652a00a60: 00007f264a61b4b8 00007f264ab7a8f9
[INFO]     [creator]       00007f2652a00a70: 0000001949544d56 00007f264abf6a25
[INFO]     [creator]       00007f2652a00a80: 00007f264a500000 0000000000000062
[INFO]     [creator]       00007f2652a00a90: 00007f2650103550 00007f264a8a8718
[INFO]     [creator]       00007f2652a00aa0: 0000000000000000 00007f264ab7b4e1
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Stacktrace Stage 0:
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a30 IP 00007f264ab5c740  FrameSize 48
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a60 IP 00007f264ab7a974  FrameSize 16
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a70 IP 00007f264ab7a8f9  FrameSize 16
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a80 IP 00007f264abf6a25  FrameSize 48
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00ab0 IP 00007f264ab7b4e1  FrameSize 32
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00ad0 IP 00007f264ab7cbc3  FrameSize 48
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00b00 IP 00007f264abf64fe  FrameSize 96
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00b60 IP 00007f264ab29ba4  FrameSize 96
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Stacktrace Stage 1:
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a30 IP 00007f264ab5c740  com.oracle.svm.core.code.CodeInfo@0x7f264a727318 name = image code
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a60 IP 00007f264ab7a974  com.oracle.svm.core.code.CodeInfo@0x7f264a727318 name = image code
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a70 IP 00007f264ab7a8f9  com.oracle.svm.core.code.CodeInfo@0x7f264a727318 name = image code
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a80 IP 00007f264abf6a25  com.oracle.svm.core.code.CodeInfo@0x7f264a727318 name = image code
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00ab0 IP 00007f264ab7b4e1  com.oracle.svm.core.code.CodeInfo@0x7f264a727318 name = image code
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00ad0 IP 00007f264ab7cbc3  com.oracle.svm.core.code.CodeInfo@0x7f264a727318 name = image code
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00b00 IP 00007f264abf64fe  com.oracle.svm.core.code.CodeInfo@0x7f264a727318 name = image code
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00b60 IP 00007f264ab29ba4  com.oracle.svm.core.code.CodeInfo@0x7f264a727318 name = image code
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Stacktrace Stage 2:
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a30 IP 00007f264ab5c740  [image code] com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.VMErrorSubstitutions.shutdown(VMErrorSubstitutions.java:111)
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a30 IP 00007f264ab5c740  [image code] com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.VMErrorSubstitutions.shouldNotReachHere(VMErrorSubstitutions.java:104)
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a60 IP 00007f264ab7a974  [image code] com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.shouldNotReachHere(VMError.java:63)
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a70 IP 00007f264ab7a8f9  [image code] com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.guarantee(VMError.java:89)
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00a80 IP 00007f264abf6a25  [image code] com.oracle.svm.jvmtiagentbase.Support.check(Support.java:417)
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00ab0 IP 00007f264ab7b4e1  [image code] com.oracle.svm.diagnosticsagent.NativeImageDiagnosticsAgent.enableCapabilities(NativeImageDiagnosticsAgent.java:243)
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00ad0 IP 00007f264ab7cbc3  [image code] com.oracle.svm.diagnosticsagent.NativeImageDiagnosticsAgent.onLoadCallback(NativeImageDiagnosticsAgent.java:128)
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00b00 IP 00007f264abf64fe  [image code] com.oracle.svm.jvmtiagentbase.JvmtiAgentBase.onLoad(JvmtiAgentBase.java:222)
[INFO]     [creator]       SP 00007f2652a00b60 IP 00007f264ab29ba4  [image code] com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.JvmtiAgentBase_onLoad_e67bdedbf3481555b89aadf746b9faadab5d0851(IsolateEnterStub.java:0)
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     [Heap settings and statistics:
[INFO]     [creator]       Supports isolates: true
[INFO]     [creator]       Object reference size: 8
[INFO]     [creator]       Incremental collections: 0
[INFO]     [creator]       Complete collections: 0]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     [Native image heap boundaries:
[INFO]     [creator]       ReadOnly Primitives: 0x7f264a501028 .. 0x7f264a5cdbf0
[INFO]     [creator]       ReadOnly References: 0x7f264a5cdc00 .. 0x7f264a698810
[INFO]     [creator]       ReadOnly Relocatables: 0x7f264a699000 .. 0x7f264a6e7648
[INFO]     [creator]       Writable Primitives: 0x7f264a6e8000 .. 0x7f264a735d60
[INFO]     [creator]       Writable References: 0x7f264a735d70 .. 0x7f264a8cff48
[INFO]     [creator]       Writable Huge: 0x0 .. 0x0
[INFO]     [creator]       ReadOnly Huge: 0x7f264a900030 .. 0x7f264a9a4410]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     [Heap:
[INFO]     [creator]       [Young generation:
[INFO]     [creator]         [Eden:
[INFO]     [creator]           [edenSpace:
[INFO]     [creator]             aligned: 0/0 unaligned: 0/0]]
[INFO]     [creator]         [Survivors:
[INFO]     [creator]           ]]
[INFO]     [creator]       [Old generation:
[INFO]     [creator]         [oldFromSpace:
[INFO]     [creator]           aligned: 0/0 unaligned: 0/0]
[INFO]     [creator]         [oldToSpace:
[INFO]     [creator]           aligned: 0/0 unaligned: 0/0]
[INFO]     [creator]         ]
[INFO]     [creator]       [Unused:
[INFO]     [creator]         aligned: 0/0]]
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Fatal error: JVMTI call failed with JVMTI_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE
[INFO]     [creator]     Error: Image build request failed with exit status 99
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to contribute native-image layer
[INFO]     [creator]     error running build
[INFO]     [creator]     exit status 99
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```